# ASP.NET Dropdown values are lost when sending to server

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am facing an issue, when submitted data from Webforms DropdownList are lost.
When I select "Technician" from my dropdownlist, same thing sends browser to server, but then in code this value is lost and instead of "Technician" (or any other value) value there is "Please select" as selected.

[Selected value in dropdown, then clicked to "Submit button"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXO5q.png)

[Data are correctly sent by browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovM2p.png)

[But in code I see different selected value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n09zu.png)

I do have:

```
if(!this.IsPostback == true)
{
  /* some SQL commands */
  DropDownList.Databind();
}
```

Do you have any suggestion how I could debug this? Or any idea what could cause this?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually this problem happens if the DropDownList options (ListItems) are added dynamically and either ViewState is not enabled on the page or control, or the options are not dynamically added on postback. It looks like you are adding them on initial load only so do you have ViewState enabled? Otherwise make sure you dynamically add options every time, I usually do this in the Page_Init event. By the way, why `!this.IsPostback == true` instead of `this.IsPostback == false` or just `!this.IsPostback)?

Comment: Thank for your tip, well I enabled ViewState for control and page, but without success. I have been using SqlDataSource on aspx page... Well probably not the best idea, because probably this datasource caused this. I have added static data (ListItems) to dropdown and then everything was OK. So at least for now, I have workaround with ListItems, but I will need to investigate it more and I will try databinding on Page_Init. And yeah, == true is useless there. Thanks